# add border color and width to 3d bar highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

I want to change border color and width of 3d bar highchart...

What I tried:

```
// Set up the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {

        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 50,
            viewDistance: 25
        }
    },
    yAxis:{
    gridLineWidth:0,
    visible:false,
    },
    xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth:0,
    categories:['Jan','feb']
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart rotation demo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Test options by dragging the sliders below'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25,
          color:'blue,
        },
        series: {

     showInLegend: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center',
                color: 'black',
                x: 0,
                y:2

            },
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            groupPadding: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [0, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }]
});
```

Getting output:
           [link for output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMXJj.png)

I want to get different colors for bar and border.....

I also tried:

column{
borderWidth:3,
borderColor:'red'
}

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `edgeColor` and `edgeWidth` properties:

```
    series: [{
        edgeColor: 'red',
        edgeWidth: 5,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx9n43os/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.edgeColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.edgeWidth

Comment: How can I change type to cylinder to get cylindrical chart.....I tried type:'cylinder'....but its showing an error

Comment: Hi @bollam_rohith, Please create a new question with additional information and `highcharts` tag.